# Magento: How to filter orders for today's date for SOAP API v2 in XML?

Tags: xml, magento, soap

I guess this is really a question about SOAP formatting. I'm trying to build a Klipfolio dashboard that will display today's order in our Magento Shop.

How do I format the created filter to request only todays's orders? I must be doing something incorrectly cause currently I only get an empty response.

Edit: There's no additional code involved. Once I get this request working I will paste into Klipfolio.

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <urn:salesOrderList>
            <urn:sessionId>XXX</urn:sessionId>
            <urn:filters>
                   <filter SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:associativeEntity[1]" xsi:type="ns1:associativeArray">
                        <item xsi:type="ns1:associativeEntity">
                            <key xsi:type="xsd:string">created_at</key>
                            <value xsi:type="xsd:string">2017-08-15 14:00:00</value>
                        </item>
                </filter>
                <urn:complex_filter/>
            </urn:filters>
        </urn:salesOrderList>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of your request?

Comment: @GerarddeVisser what I posted above is the request. No code involved, just SOAP/XML, the format that Klipfolio uses.